# Facebook: How best to get people to like/comment the original post, when sharing a post?

Tags: facebook, sharing

My wife has a Facebook account for her business, and a personal Facebook account.  What she tends to do is to post from her business account, and then *share* those posts on her personal account.

What tends to happen next is that she gets lots of likes and comments on her personal account about the post which she shared, but the original post itself doesn't get any likes or comments, or not many anyway.

She often writes, when sharing, "If you want to like or comment, please do it on the original post, thanks!" or words to that effect, but, generally speaking, people don't, and so all the Facebook activity goes onto her personal account, not her business account.

It would be helpful for her business if the original post was getting the likes and comments instead.  Are there any good ways to try to make this happen?  Is there a better way for her to share her business posts on her personal account?

Grateful for any advice, thanks.